# I can't debbug applications - ADB is not responding

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb

I'm using Intellij IDEA 12.0.2 on Windows 8 and I have problem with debbuging apps. I can't run my application on phone or emulator because all the time I'm getting alerts: Waiting for ADB or ADB is not resonding.

I tried:
    restarting IDEA
    killing adb.exe
    killing and starting server
    editing run configuration
    launching IDEA as administrator

Nothing works. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It works fine from the command line. AV/FW was causing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling your firewall or any other A/V solution you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your platform tools are up to date, I've heard that this was very common on versions less than revision 18.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running IntelliJ as administrator - worked for me at once.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.The cause was that I have a utility software already running adb. Uninstalling that software fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First I run the command "netstat -ano | findstr "5037" to find the program which use the port 5037.
Then use "taskkill /F /PID xxxx" to kill that program.

"adb start-server " to start the adb server.

Last ,restart your Intellij Idea.

I just put the solution in my blog [enter link description here](http://www.textworld.me/intellij-adb-not-response/)